Why isn't a background notification task running when a notification comes in? Expo-notifications
I am building a react native Android/IOS app using Expo and I need to have a scheduled notification come in and run some code regardless of whether the app is in the foreground or background.
I currently have this background task defined with Expo:
TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK, ({data, error, executionInfo}) => {
    console.log('Received a notification in the background!');
    Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
        content: {
            title: "HOORAY",
            body: 'HOORAY',
            data: {type: 'pre'}
        },
        trigger: {
            seconds: 10,
        },
    });
});

Notifications.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK);

Which is all done in the global scope as per the docs
I have tried to use the Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync (shown below) and tried sending a push notification from the Firebase dashboard and I receive them fine but the background notification task doesn't run regardless of whether the app is in the foreground or background.
Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
  content: {
    title: "Example title",
    body: 'Example body',
    data: {test: 'true'}
  },
  trigger: {
    seconds: 10,
  },
});

It's also worth noting that the task is being registered, TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync() gives me this [{"options": {}, "taskName": "BACKGROUND-NOTIFICATION-TASK", "taskType": "remote-notification"}]
From what I understand from the docs the background notification task I have set in TaskManager should run when a notification comes in, regardless of whether the app is in the foreground or background as per the docs
I am running an Expo (version 51.0.10) development build on a real Android device (Pixel 7 Pro).
Where am I going wrong?

According to the issue below, the background task only works for data-only notifications.
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/29622
